# Scroll gridpane on touch in JavaFX

Tags: java, scroll, javafx, javafx-8

I have a GridPane inside a ScrollPane.

I need to scroll the gridpane when a drag event (touch) is fired. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setPannable(true)` on the `ScrollPane`.